# How to make xscreensaver turn off the backlight only when explicitly locked

Tags: linux, power-management, screensaver, backlight, xscreensaver

Is it possible to set up **XScreensaver** so that it would turn the LCD backlight off only when I lock the screen by hand?

I thought it must be controlled by the "*Quick Power-off in Blank Only Mode*", but this option seems to work only in combination with *Standby/Suspend/Off* options. So what may be a good way of keeping the screen backlight off when the screen is locked?

Answer (score 7):

It seems that the "Quick Power-Off in Blank Only Mode" is only enabled when power management is enabled (makes sense, however the GUI implies otherwise IMO).

I have set every timed power management option to one minute and enabled the quick power-off option. Now whenever I lock manually the screen powers-off immediately. When I push a button the screen powers back on and powers off after one minute.

[image: Power options]

It should be noted that power management is also applied when not in screensaver.

Comment: > however the GUI implies otherwise IMO

 - Exactly!
I did try this method before posting my question. The reason I do not use it as you suggested is that I need my screen to stay on **all the** time except when PC is locked.

Comment: It should also be noted that setting Display Mode to `Disable Screen Saver` also disables Power Management.